# connecting rstudio to azure container

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, rstudio

I'm currently attempting to establish a connection between RStudio and Azure services, but I'm encountering an error that's preventing successful authentication. Here's the specific error message:

|                                                                                                                         |   0%Error in process_storage_response(response, match.arg(http_status_handler),  :
Forbidden (HTTP 403). Failed to complete Storage Services operation. Message:
AuthenticationFailed
Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:2d63d4f3-201e-0100-1e57-60f381000000
Time:2024-02-15T21:38:30.5624603Z

original code:

```
bl_endp_key <- storage_endpoint(account_endpoint, key=account_key , sas = sas)
cont <- storage_container(bl_endp_key, container_name)
w_con <- textConnection("foo", "w")
write.csv(df, w_con)
r_con <- textConnection(textConnectionValue(w_con))
close(w_con)
upload_blob(cont, src=r_con, dest="df.csv")
close(con)
```

Answer (score 1):

> 0%Error in process_storage_response(response, match.arg(http_status_handler), : Forbidden (HTTP 403). Failed tocomplete Storage Services operation. Message: AuthenticationFailedServer failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.RequestId:2d63d4f3-201e-0100-1e57-60f381000000 Time:2024-02-15T21:38:30.5624603Z

The above error occurred due to passing both **`account key`** and **`sas token`**; you need to pass either one of them.

Here is the corrected code to upload a CSV file to Azure Blob Storage:

**Code:**

```
library(AzureStor)

df <- data.frame(Column1 = c('Dhoni', 'Sachin', 'Virat'),
                 Column2 = c('Best finisher', 'God of cricket', 'Best batsman'))

account_endpoint <- "https://venkat789.blob.core.windows.net"
account_key <- "xxx"
container_name <- "sample"
bl_endp_key <- storage_endpoint(account_endpoint, key=account_key)
cont <- storage_container(bl_endp_key, container_name)
w_con <- textConnection("foo", "w")
write.csv(df, w_con)
r_con <- textConnection(textConnectionValue(w_con))
close(w_con)
upload_blob(cont, src=r_con, dest="df.csv")
close(r_con)
```

**Output:**

[image]

To upload CSV with the SAS token same as the above code and you can generate SAS token from the portal.

***Portal -> storage account -> Sharedaccesssignature -> check the required permission -> generate sas.***

**Portal:**

[image]

Comment: I removed the access key and and received this message:
 Forbidden (HTTP 403). Failed to complete Storage Services operation. Message:
AuthorizationPermissionMismatch
This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.

Comment: How you are generating sas token?

Comment: Create SAS token with `write` permission and proper expiry date for a blob container it will upload your csv file.

Comment: Edited the answer. Hope it address your issue.